# Timer trigger azure function with table storage input binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azureportal, azure-triggers

so I have an azure table that has a list of users (identified by the row and partition key) and their activityStatus which is either 1 (completed) or 0 (not completed).

I am trying to make a simple azure function that checks the activityStatus of every user every day at 5pm and records the row and partition keys of all the users who have not completed their exercises to a different azure table.

So I created a timer triggered azure function set to trigger every day at 5 pm, and then created an input and output binding to my azure tables and now I have no idea what to do next?

I can't find any tutorials of how to read the input table data from my timer triggered azure function and also how to filter data using the activityStatus entity and then how to record and enter the data to a new table.

Any help or direction to a good tutorial/resource would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a timer trigger:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#example

And the CRON expression should be `0 0 17 * * *`

You also need a azure table storage input binding:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=csharp#example

Comment: Hi thanks, but I've already looked at those tutorials and have made a function that is timer triggered. I just don't know how to do the next part of actually being able to extract the values from the table entities for every signal user